# Confused with encoding and decoding with Kafka connect

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, amazon-kinesis

Here's a high-level view of my pipeline:

**MQTT -> Kafka/MQTT bridge [producer] -> Kafka connect -> AWS Kinesis data stream -> Lambda function (decode Kinesis.record.data) -> store DynamoDB**

Basically, the full flow is working properly but I'm getting a weird "json" format when I'm trying to read the kinesis.record.data.

It isn't utf8. It includes utf8-encoded quoted-string-encoded-JSON records separated by a binary header (so it looks like it's JSON that's gone through a printed-quotable filter and then got packed into a binary format). I don't think it's anything Kinesis-specific and I've been wasting countless hours debugging - it has to come from the Kafka producer or in-between, Kafka connect...

Here's the python code, I'm running to grab my metrics from various MQTT topics and send the message to my Kafka producer, using kafka-python:

```
kafka_producer = KafkaProducer( bootstrap_servers= "10.0.0.129:9092",
                                value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
data = {
                "datetime": str(datetime.now()),
                "topic": str(msg.topic),
                "value": str(msg.payload.decode()),
                "environment": "test-v1"
        }
kafka_producer.send("greenforge-events", data)
```

And I'm running Kafka in connect-distributed mode with the properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
group.id=connect-cluster
#key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
#value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
config.storage.topic=connect-configs
config.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.topic=connect-status
status.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=/opt/kafka/plugins
```

I've read a bit about encoding and decoding on Kafka connect, but I'm new to this. As you can see from my python code, I'm sending successfully my JSON (as a string, but in the property file I tried to set it to JSONConverter with no success)...

And here's my connector config:

```
name=greenforges
connector.class=com.amazon.kinesis.kafka.AmazonKinesisSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=greenforge-events
region=us-east-2
streamName=greenforge-prototype-stream
usePartitionAsHashKey=false
flushSync=true
# Use new Kinesis Producer for each Partition
singleKinesisProducerPerPartition=true
# Whether to block new records from putting onto Kinesis Producer if 
# threshold for outstandings records have reached 
pauseConsumption=true
outstandingRecordsThreshold=500000
# If outstanding records on producers are beyond threshold sleep for following period (in ms) 
sleepPeriod=1000
# If outstanding records on producers are not cleared sleep for following cycle before killing the tasks
sleepCycles=10
# Kinesis Producer Configuration - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer/blob/master/java/amazon-kinesis-producer-sample/default_config.properties
# All kinesis producer configuration have not been exposed
maxBufferedTime=1500
maxConnections=1
rateLimit=100
ttl=60000
metricsLevel=detailed
metricsGranuality=shard
metricsNameSpace=KafkaKinesisStreamsConnector
aggregation=true
```

Finally, when I try reading the kinesis.record.data this is what I get:

```
const stream = "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";
        
var payload = Buffer.from(stream, 'base64').toString('utf8');
console.log('Decoded payload: %s', payload);
```

Here's the log:

```
Decoded payload: ��
0��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.143649",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility1/airpressure",
    "value": "{\"hecto pascals\": 642}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.158318",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility1/casingtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": 8}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.177738",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility1/co2",
    "value": "{\"parts per million\": 1346}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.185060",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility3/airtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": -22.902578536320426}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.192788",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility3/airpressure",
    "value": "{\"hecto pascals\": 1054}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.205576",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility9/highlevelfloatswitch",
    "value": "{\"enabled\": true}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.222200",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility9/airpressure",
    "value": "{\"hecto pascals\": 748}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.227888",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility6/casingtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": 15.033848487510769}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.265882",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility9/solenoidvalve",
    "value": "{\"enabled\": false}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:16.271186",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility9/casingtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": -2.9946955079167408}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.171244",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility1/airtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": -13.215548803641157}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.177993",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility1/co2",
    "value": "{\"parts per million\": 1346}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.185670",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility3/airtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": -22.902578536320426}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.193153",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility3/airpressure",
    "value": "{\"hecto pascals\": 1054}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.219201",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility6/airtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": 45.80449060789106}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
��
{
    "datetime": "2022-10-11 14:46:17.229977",
    "topic": "greenforge/uuid/utility6/casingtemperature",
    "value": "{\"celsius\": 15.033848487510769}",
    "environment": "test-v1"
}
�G3�=
��o� ��
```

I'm 110% sure that the weird characters represent the stream record data structure for example something along those lines:

```
(
 topic='greenforge-events',
 partition=0,
 offset=24,
 timestamp=21321421312312,
 key=None,
 value={JSON_Object},
 checksum=321321,
 serialized_key_size=-1
 serialized_value_size=49
)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Didn't, but firstly - Lambda supports reading from Kafka, so why do you even need Kinesis, and therefore Connect? Or, I think there's a Connector for Dynamo, right?

Comment: My Kafka is running on-premise, locally. Would that work?

Comment: What's stopping you from running Kafka in AWS with MSK? Do you really need the intermediate step for Kinesis? Also, did you try `ByteArrayConverter` in Connect settings since you dont really need to "process" the data? Also, your data isn't base64 encoded anywhere, unless Kinesis does that on its own

Comment: I want to run Kafka locally to handle offline mode - it seemed like the best approach. Instead of doing something custom between MQTT and SQLite... for example.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest SQLite. Maybe Postgres or Mongo, then use Debezium to source data from that. That didn't answer other part of my question about the converter. And your JS code seems to be missing `JSON.parse`, but can you please show the console log output?

Comment: FYI I added the logs to my lambda function. Actually, I said SQLite - but it's more like influxdb for time-series (or yes, MongoDB would be good too). I'm do have the JSON.parse but it returns an error because it doesn't recognize the first character and throw an exception for invalid token.
I did not try ByteArrayConverter - would it be just for the "value.converter" property.

Comment: _would it be just for the "value.converter" property_ -  yes, since your python code only sends values, so the keys would be null, anyway. Like I said, it's not really clear to me where the Base64 conversion is happening. I looked at the source code for the Kinesis connector, and I don't see it happening there. Also, not really clear how you have multiple events being part of the same payload, but I'm guessing those `�` characters represent some binary delimiter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248764/discussion-between-fneron-and-onecricketeer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the printed payload, the data is being batched together within Kinesis, and in some custom binary format

You'd probably want individual Kinesis records that you can parse and insert row-by-row into your downstream systems, so you can set

```
aggregation=false
```

https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector#kafka-kinesis-streams-connectorproperties

Then `JSON.parse(payload)` in the lambda should work.

If you did want to batch records together, you can do that in Python

```
kafka_producer = ...

counter = 0
events = []
for msg in mqtt_consumer:
    data = {
        "datetime": str(datetime.now()),
        "topic": msg.topic,
        "value": msg.payload.decode(),
        "environment": "test-v1"
    }
    events.append(data)
    counter += 1
    if counter % 10 == 0:  # for example, 10 at a time
        kafka_producer.send("greenforge-events", events)
        events.clear()
        counter = 0
if events:  # send remainder if for-loop exits with error
    kafka_producer.send("greenforge-events", events)
```